# My output is giving the numbers instead of asterisks, how do I show asterisks there instead?

Tags: vb.net

Output I am getting -

[image]

What I am trying to get -

[image]

Hi, I am trying to create a program that takes calories in daily and charts them in a daily summary and a weekly summary but with asterisks, but I cant figure out how to make asterisks show as in place of the numbers, like " ***** " instead of 5. I included pictures of the output I am getting as well as what i am supposed to get as well as the code I have so far. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Public Class frmA9
    
'Global Variables
    Dim printedHeaderDaily As Boolean = False

    'Global Constaints 
    Const FILL_SPACE As Integer = 2
    Const DAY_HEADING As String = "Day"
    Const TIME_HEADING As String = "Time"
    Const TOTAL_HEADING As String = " "
    Const TIME_LABEL_1 As String = " 5-11 AM"
    Const TIME_LABEL_2 As String = " 11-5 PM"
    Const TIME_LABEL_3 As String = " 5-11 PM"
    Const TIME_LABEL_4 As String = " 11-5 AM"
    Const TIME_RANGE_1 As Integer = 1
    Const TIME_RANGE_2 As Integer = 2
    Const TIME_RANGE_3 As Integer = 3
    Const TIME_RANGE_4 As Integer = 4
    Const TIME_LEN As Integer = 7
    Const TIME_IDX_START_1 As Integer = 5
    Const TIME_IDX_START_2 As Integer = 14
    Const TIME_IDX_START_3 As Integer = 23
    Const TIME_IDX_START_4 As Integer = 32

   

    Private Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAddtoSummary.Click

        Dim existingIdx As Integer = -1
        Dim dayformat As String = "{0,3}" & Space(FILL_SPACE) &
                                     "{1,7:N0}" & Space(FILL_SPACE) &
                                     "{2,7:N0}" & Space(FILL_SPACE) &
                                     "{3,7:N0}" & Space(FILL_SPACE) &
                                     "{4,7:N0}"
        'Is header needed
        If Not printedHeaderDaily Then
            'Insert header
            lstDailySummary.Items.Add(String.Format(dayformat,
                                                    DAY_HEADING,
                                                    TIME_LABEL_1,
                                                    TIME_LABEL_2,
                                                    TIME_LABEL_3,
                                                    TIME_LABEL_4))

            'Avoid repeating header
            printedHeaderDaily = True
        End If

        'Search for day in existing list
        existingIdx = lstDailySummary.FindString(determineDay)

        'Replace existing or insert new
        If existingIdx > -1 Then
            'Replace
            lstDailySummary.Items.Item(existingIdx) = String.Format(dayformat,
                                                                    determineDay,
                                                                    CInt(txt5AM.Text),
                                                                    CInt(txt11AM.Text),
                                                                    CInt(txt5PM.Text),
                                                                    CInt(txt11PM.Text))
        Else
            'New
            lstDailySummary.Items.Add(String.Format(dayformat,
                                                    determineDay,
                                                      CInt(txt5AM.Text),
                                                      CInt(txt11AM.Text),
                                                      CInt(txt5PM.Text),
                                                      CInt(txt11PM.Text)))
        End If

        'Display weekly total
        updateWeeklyTotatl()
    End Sub

    Sub updateWeeklyTotatl()
        Dim totalTimeOne As Long
        Dim totalTimeTwo As Long
        Dim totalTimeThree As Long
        Dim totalTimeFour As Long
        Dim totalWeek As Long
        Dim headerformat As String = "{0,-10:S}{1,6:S}"
        Dim detailFormat As String = "{0,-10}{1,6:N0}"

        'Remove existing data
        lstWeekSummary.Items.Clear()

        'Sum individual time ranges
        totalTimeOne = sumCalForTime(TIME_RANGE_1)
        totalTimeTwo = sumCalForTime(TIME_RANGE_2)
        totalTimeThree = sumCalForTime(TIME_RANGE_3)
        totalTimeFour = sumCalForTime(TIME_RANGE_4)

        'Sum entire week
        totalWeek = totalTimeOne + totalTimeTwo + totalTimeThree + totalTimeFour

        'Insert header row
        lstWeekSummary.Items.Add(String.Format(headerformat, TIME_HEADING, TOTAL_HEADING))

        'Add bar for each time range
        lstWeekSummary.Items.Add(String.Format(detailFormat, TIME_LABEL_1, totalTimeOne))
        lstWeekSummary.Items.Add(String.Format(detailFormat, TIME_LABEL_2, totalTimeTwo))
        lstWeekSummary.Items.Add(String.Format(detailFormat, TIME_LABEL_3, totalTimeThree))
        lstWeekSummary.Items.Add(String.Format(detailFormat, TIME_LABEL_4, totalTimeFour))
    End Sub

    Function determineDay() As String
        Dim selectedDay As String

        'Identify the selected Day
        If rdbSun.Checked Then
            selectedDay = "Sun"
        ElseIf rdbMon.Checked Then
            selectedDay = "Mon"
        ElseIf rdbTues.Checked Then
            selectedDay = "Tues"
        ElseIf rdbWed.Checked Then
            selectedDay = "Wed"
        ElseIf rdbThurs.Checked Then
            selectedDay = "Thurs"
        ElseIf rdbFri.Checked Then
            selectedDay = "Fri"
        ElseIf rdbSat.Checked Then
            selectedDay = "Sat"
        End If

        Return selectedDay
    End Function

    Function determineStartIndex(ByVal timeRange As Integer) As Integer
        Dim startIndex As Integer

        'Identify start index of given time range
        Select Case timeRange
            Case TIME_RANGE_1
                startIndex = TIME_IDX_START_1
            Case TIME_RANGE_2
                startIndex = TIME_IDX_START_2
            Case TIME_RANGE_3
                startIndex = TIME_IDX_START_3
            Case TIME_RANGE_4
                startIndex = TIME_IDX_START_4
        End Select

        Return startIndex
    End Function

    Function sumCalForTime(ByVal timeRange As Integer) As Long
        Dim CalSum As Long
        Dim startIndex As Integer

        'Find index of first number in given time range
        startIndex = determineStartIndex(timeRange)

        'Iterate through the daily summary
        'Sum all water consumed in the given range
        For idxRow As Integer = 1 To lstDailySummary.Items.Count - 1
            CalSum += CLng(lstDailySummary.Items.Item(idxRow).ToString.Substring(startIndex, TIME_LEN))
        Next

        Return CalSum
    End Function

    Private Sub btnClear_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClear.Click
        'Remove daily entries
        lstDailySummary.Items.Clear()

        'Remove weekly summary
        lstWeekSummary.Items.Clear()

        'Ensure daily header is printed after each entry
        printedHeaderDaily = False
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the String class constructor overload that accept two parameters: character and repeat times:

```
New String("*"c, 5) ' = *****
```

So, Change the following lines:

```
'Add bar for each time range
lstWeekSummary.Items.Add(String.Format(detailFormat, TIME_LABEL_1, totalTimeOne))
lstWeekSummary.Items.Add(String.Format(detailFormat, TIME_LABEL_2, totalTimeTwo))
lstWeekSummary.Items.Add(String.Format(detailFormat, TIME_LABEL_3, totalTimeThree))
lstWeekSummary.Items.Add(String.Format(detailFormat, TIME_LABEL_4, totalTimeFour))
```

To:

```
'Add bar for each time range
lstWeekSummary.Items.Add(String.Format(detailFormat, TIME_LABEL_1, New String("*"c, totalTimeOne)))
lstWeekSummary.Items.Add(String.Format(detailFormat, TIME_LABEL_2, New String("*"c,totalTimeTwo)))
lstWeekSummary.Items.Add(String.Format(detailFormat, TIME_LABEL_3, New String("*"c,totalTimeThree)))
lstWeekSummary.Items.Add(String.Format(detailFormat, TIME_LABEL_4, New String("*"c,totalTimeFour)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Danielle,

It would be easy to convert your number to a series of asterisk.

```
New String("*"c, totalTimeOne)
```

I don't think that will solve your issue. You are totaling the calories for a day and will come up with a number (e.g. for 5-11AM the total is 2600). You then have a series of headers for calories. Your max is 18310, and 2600 is 14% of the total. Let's say you have a max of 200 characters in your list box. You would multiply .14*200 which = 28. So then you would print out 28 asterisks.

```
New String("*"c, 28)
```

This could look something like this:

```
Sub updateWeeklyTotatl()
        Dim totalTimeOne As Long
        Dim totalTimeTwo As Long
        Dim totalTimeThree As Long
        Dim totalTimeFour As Long
        Dim totalWeek As Long
        Dim totalAsterisk As Long = 200 'set this to your total number of Asterisks possible
        Dim maxWeekSummary As Long = 18310 'set this to the max number in chart
        Dim headerformat As String = "{0,-10:S}{1,6:S}"
        Dim detailFormat As String = "{0,-10}{1,6:N0}"

        'Remove existing data
        lstWeekSummary.Items.Clear()

        'Sum individual time ranges
        totalTimeOne = sumCalForTime(TIME_RANGE_1)
        totalTimeTwo = sumCalForTime(TIME_RANGE_2)
        totalTimeThree = sumCalForTime(TIME_RANGE_3)
        totalTimeFour = sumCalForTime(TIME_RANGE_4)

        'Sum entire week
        totalWeek = totalTimeOne + totalTimeTwo + totalTimeThree + totalTimeFour

        'Insert header row
        lstWeekSummary.Items.Add(String.Format(headerformat, TIME_HEADING, TOTAL_HEADING))

        'Add bar for each time range
        ' this formula will calculate the number of asterisks to show CInt((totalTimeOne / maxWeekSummary) * totalAsterisk)
        lstWeekSummary.Items.Add(String.Format(detailFormat, TIME_LABEL_1, New String("*"c, CInt((totalTimeOne / maxWeekSummary) * totalAsterisk))))
        lstWeekSummary.Items.Add(String.Format(detailFormat, TIME_LABEL_2, New String("*"c, CInt((totalTimeTwo / maxWeekSummary) * totalAsterisk))))
        lstWeekSummary.Items.Add(String.Format(detailFormat, TIME_LABEL_3, New String("*"c, CInt((totalTimeThree / maxWeekSummary) * totalAsterisk))))
        lstWeekSummary.Items.Add(String.Format(detailFormat, TIME_LABEL_4, New String("*"c, CInt((totalTimeFour / maxWeekSummary) * totalAsterisk))))
    End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, you are right it didn't solve the entire issue. So, those headers for calories are 25%, ,50%, 75%, and 100% of the total number of calories entered. Do you know how I would go about doing that in the code? Or at least where I could start? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sure you would need to know the number that is equivalent to 100%. Say that number is 25,000. Take the total for the day, to to make it simple lets say 2,500. Divide 2,500/25,000 = .10 or 10%. Then you need to know how many asterisks = 100% Let say 200 asterisks = 100%. Multiply .10 * 200 = 20. Then print out 20 asterisks.

Comment: Thanks! How/Where do I start that in the code itself if you don't mind explaining that? I'm really lost!

Comment: I've edited the answer above to show one possibility